Sending text with few embedded images as a single message by making one WhatsApp cloud API call
We want to send messages to our customers using WhatsApp cloud APIs. A single message could have some text , links , a videos and couples images. Is it possible to send these content as a single message by making one API call ?
We’re considering using a Utility template to combine text and multimedia in a single message, as these templates allow a single image or a video in the header section. However, our use case requires including more than one image in the message. What’s the best way to implement this?
